# json_decode return null if json with special character for example &,#

Tags: php, json, laravel

For API - JSON decode returns null, if the data has special character like &,#.

```
$custom_name = json_decode($request->custom_name);

// custom_name=[{"id":"1","name":"ff#&test"},{"id":"12","name":"test1"}]
print_r($custom_name); // returns null
```

I displayed `json_last_error()` - it display as error code 3

How to handle this data.

Comment: My localhost url should be like that : http://localhost/client/mike/api/shopping_cart?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEwMDAyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L2NsaWVudC9taWtlL2FwaS9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU0MDk2NTQ3NywiZXhwIjoxNTQzNTU3NDc3LCJuYmYiOjE1NDA5NjU0NzcsImp0aSI6InVJeTBCcEw4eDNrcmZKWTkifQ.XFMsXn7fKnAVy4_j3oEvtt-1scdqVPz0Ty00uvGBYSM&custom_name=[{%22id%22:%22260%22,%22name%22:%22ss#%22}]

Comment: `json_decode('[{"id":"1","name":"ff#&test"},{"id":"12","name":"test1"}]')` works fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: My advice would be not to put JSON in your URL at all. If you want to send JSON to the server, use a POST request instead. Then URL-encoding issues will not be a problem

Comment: The code in your comment works flawlessly. If you want to read from the URL, make sure you use `encodeURIComponent`, since the hash-tag is, how can I call it, "preserved"?

Comment: @FrankyW. if you want to _read_ from an encoded URL, you'd need [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). And I suspect you mean "reserved" (i.e. a special character with its own meaning in a URL) instead of "preserved" :-)